# how to set initial value of session variable as 'zero'?

Tags: php

I have created session variables such as `$_SESSION[coun]` and `$_SESSION[coun1]` where on button click its value get incremented or decremented numerically for eg such as 1,2 or -1,-2 etc. Actually I want to make values of  `$_SESSION[coun]` and `$_SESSION[coun1]` equal to zero such as '0' when I leave page or when I visit page it should be initially 'zero' such as '0' or how can I unset these session variables when I am not on same page instead I am on others pages.  I hope I am clear about my thoughts.

Comment: Well actually I solved my problem by including unset($_SESSION["coun"]); unset($_SESSION["coun1"]) ; on other pages so that when I navigate , I just found my these variables initially unset when I visit the same page. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either initialize the session count variable always, or do a simple check at the output.

```
//variant a: variable initialization
if (!isset($_SESSION["count"]))
   $_SESSION["count"] = 0;

//variant b: output 0 if empty
$myOutput = isset($_SESSION["count"]) ? $_SESSION["count"] : 0;
```